# IIS App Pool

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool

If my host automatically recycles the app pool when it reaches a certain size will this cause all users sessions to be lost and the user to be logged out?

If this is the case would moving InProc sessions to SQL fix the issue? Would doing this also save much memory?

Thanks

Gavin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all user sessions in the pool are gone.
If you use an out-of-proc SQL Server, it will survive app pool resets.
see http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20021016.asp for some more remarks.

It will save memory on your IIS server, but be aware of the performance considerations.

Comment: Would it persist any logins that were made using the ASP.Net Membership model? I'm aware of the performance but not sure I have much choice as my host recycles the app pool every time it gets to 100mb

Answer (score 0):

Yes, moving the sessions to SQL Server would solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, moving to an out of process solution for sessions will fix this issue.